# Camera overlay does not fill the entire screen when orientation is changed on iPad, Titanium SDK 6.0.0 and later

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am working on a Titanium app and I am facing a problem on iPad after upgrading the Titanium SDK to 6.0.0 and later.

I am using overlay for the Camera, but when I change the orientation the overlay also rotates but it is not filling the entire screen, looks like the overlay keeps the width and the height before the rotating.

```
    var overlay = Ti.UI.createView({
        width : Ti.UI.FILL,
        height : Ti.UI.FILL,
    });

    var buttonHolder = Ti.UI.createView({
        width : Ti.UI.FILL,
        height : 70,
        backgroundColor : 'black',
        opacity : 0.5,
        bottom : 0
    });

    var bCancel = Ti.UI.createButton({
        width : 70,
        height : Ti.UI.FILL,
        color : 'white',
        title : "Cancel",
        textAlign : 'left',
        backgroundColor : undefined,
        left : 0
    });

    var bTakePicture = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        width : Ti.UI.SIZE,
        height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
        image : 'image.png',
    });

    var bDone = Ti.UI.createButton({
        width : 70,
        height : Ti.UI.FILL,
        color : 'white',
        title : "Done",
        textAlign : 'left',
        right : 0,
        backgroundColor : undefined
    });

    buttonHolder.add(bCancel);
    buttonHolder.add(bTakePicture);
    buttonHolder.add(bDone);

    overlay.add(buttonHolder);

    Titanium.Media.showCamera({
        overlay : overlay,
        showControls : false,

        success : function(event) {
        },
        cancel : function() {
        },
        error : function(error) {
        },
        allowImageEditing : false,
        saveToPhotoGallery : false
    });
```

I tried to change the width and the height when orientation is changed but without success.

This is working fine on 5.5.1 SDK.

Can someone please help me, am I doing something wrong, is there some change in the 6.0.0 SDK related to this one...

Thanks.

I am attaching screenshots showing the problem, the yellow color is the overlay.

[Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OGSF.jpg)

[Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctab2.jpg)

Comment: I'm also having this problem, have not found a solution or workaround yet...